# What word can describe a person who is recovering but in the end fails to

Tags: single-word-requests, word-choice

I need a word that describes a person who is recovering from a mental  treatment(lets say depresion), fairly well but in the end when they are about to be discharge from treatment they fall back again and have to start over.

Comment: When requesting single words you need to include an example sentence with a blank where the word would be. Without any sentence context, it can be hard or futile for people to figure out a acceptable word.

Comment: Relapse is a word which describes the situation you describe.

Comment: Also please explain whether you are talking about someone with whom this behaviour is habitual, ie has occurred frequently.

Answer (score 2):

In medical terms, a **relapsed** person is someone who suffers a further deterioration after an apparent recovery of health (either physical health or mental health).

> Relapse a. To suffer from a recurrence of an illness after an interval of recovery; (of an illness or disease process) to recur in this way. Also fig.
>
> 2008   Guardian 23 Oct. 1/1   A three-year trial at Cambridge University showed that patients given the drug, alemtuzumab, were 74% less likely to relapse than those treated with existing medications.

[OED-3](http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/161798?rskey=MNK9o2&result=3&isAdvanced=false#eid)

In behavioural terms, someone who relapses into previous, say, criminal behaviour is usually referred to as a **recividist**.

> Recividism :The action of relapsing into crime, or reoffending, esp. habitually; the tendency to behave in this way.
>
> 1971   Sci. Amer. May 51/1   There is no strong evidence..that recidivism increases with leniency of sentence.

[OED-3](http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/159514?redirectedFrom=recidivism#eid)

Comment: Of course, because of the poor question, this doesn't actually describe the *person.*

Comment: @AndrewLeach I was expecting an edit along those lines, but instead I have edited my answer.